# Form Block module usage in multiple sections

Tags: 7, blocks, users

While working a project i came across an issue with ["Form Block"](http://drupal.org/project/formblock) module. I used this block on a basic page in content section. Now my client also wants this same block in the right sidebar on the home page. Is there a way out to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) to achieve this. With this module you can show the same block in different regions on different pages. You can add a condition (like path is "/frontpage") and a reaction like show block xy in region xy.

Comment: Hey volker, I just added this context module its working great. But is not giving an option to display the block only on the home page..!

Comment: You have to add a condition of sort "path" from the dropdown and then add the path to your homepage (I assume it's the frontpage) in the text field like this: <front>. Then add the block in the region you wish below...

Comment: There's a good overview for this module over at mustardseed: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode38